# How to project a spherical map onto a sphere / cube:  "Equirectangular to cubic"

Tags: c++, opencv, geometry, projection, panoramas

UPDATE:
I found that, http://os.ivrpa.org/panosalado/wiki , has an implementation in java. Anyone who has something similar in c or c++?

I have this panorama, an spherical map from google streetview, and want to map this on a sphere/cube. Below are some examples and illustrations, what i seek is a library that can do it, or some implementation guides.

[image: panorama]

I tried http://krpano.com/docu/tutorials/quickstart/#top that gives the results listed at the bottom. It illustrates what i want, but the rotation axis is off. I need to create the views of direct ahead and back, left and right. Ideal i would like to map it to the sphere and tell it what angles to extract (the orientation of the cube).

[Back,Down,Front,Left,Right,Up]

[image: Back]
[image: Down]
[image: Font]
[image: Left]
[image: Right]
[image: Up]

Comment: The input image is 360x180 degree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this easily in [POV-Ray](http://www.povray.org/) putting the camera in the middle of a sphere mapped with your texture.  See [`image_map map_type 1`](http://www.povray.org/documentation/view/3.6.1/408/) and e.g [this example](http://www.f-lohmueller.de/pov_tut/backgrnd/p_sky8.htm).

But really this is very easy to implement yourself, assuming the input images are some sort of cylindrical equidistant or equirectangular projection: for each (x,y) in the output image you are rendering, just use the [inverse formulas](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CylindricalEquidistantProjection.html) to compute a (longitude,latitude) in the input image and interpolate/copy over a pixel value.

Comment: It looks interesting, but i think I am looking for a simpler solution, some c++ code where i can tweak the parameters and use it in my algorithm. Will see if others come with some answers before accepting.